# Devise current_user in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

Is there any way to access the current user in routes.rb? I would like a mapping like this:

```
match /profile => redirect("/profiles/{current_user.name}")
```

`env['warden']` doesn't seem to be set up, so I can't access `warden.user.name`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on user1136228's answer:

```
get '/profile', to: redirect { |params, request|
  me = request.env["warden"].user(:user)
  me ? ('/profiles/' + me.name) : '/'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure that's possible. However, you could use a controller:

```
def profile
    if signed_in?
        redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user)
    else
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done this and it's a decent workaround, but gets repetitive when you have multiple convenience URLs related to the current user (edit_profile_path etc.).

Comment: everything is always possible and achievable.

Answer (score 3):

The are two possibilities.
If you are using devise you can use warden like so:

```
current_user = request.env["warden"].user(:user)
```

or without warden

```
User.find_by_id(request.session[:user_id])
```

if you store your user's id in session's :user_id

Comment: You can add constaraint in routes.rb